# Insert text at specific position in a file in TCL

Tags: tcl

My task is to insert a text at any given position in a file from TCL script.

What I have tried is:

```
set a [open "C:/TAT_DATA/temp.txt" a+]
seek $a -8 end
puts $a "insert between"
close $a
```

But It is replacing/overwriting the existing content. Can I do something else?
I DO NOT want to read whole file content.

Comment: Well you don't have to read the _whole_ file content, but you're going to have to read some of it.

Comment: How can we do that? The way I am doing below or some other technique is their?

Comment: I think you'll find that operating systems don't work in the way that you assume they do. Inserting (or deleting) text _except at the end of the file_ requires rewriting.

Comment: The `insertIntoFile` command in the `fileutil` module does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the way:

```
set a [open "C:/TAT_DATA/temp.txt" a+]
#go to the specific position
seek $a -9 end
#read the data till end
set data [read $a]
#again move pointer to previous position
seek $a -9 end
#insert data (along with the previous data overwriting the existing data)
puts $a "insert between $data"
close $a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package require fileutil
namespace import fileutil::*

set filename "C:/TAT_DATA/temp.txt"
set pos [expr {[file size $filename] - 9}]
insertIntoFile $filename $pos "insert between"
```

The commands in the `fileutil` module are really helpful. You can set the contents of a file in one command:

```
writeFile $filename foobarfoobar
```

look at the contents:

```
cat $filename
# -> foobarfoobar
```

add more content:

```
appendToFile $filename baz
# file contents: foobarfoobarbaz
```

insert content:

```
insertIntoFile $filename 6 123456
# file contents: foobar123456foobarbaz
```

remove content:

```
removeFromFile $filename 7 4
# file contents: foobar16foobarbaz
```

replace content:

```
replaceInFile $filename 6 2 --==--
# file contents: foobar--==--foobarbaz
```

or process the contents with a command:

```
writeFile $filename "a b c"
proc foo data {
    foreach item $data {
        lappend res ($item)
    }
    join $res -
}
updateInPlace $filename foo
# file contents: (a)-(b)-(c)
```

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm), [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)